# Mapping a string Array to an Object using ValueInjecter

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, valueinjecter, object-object-mapping

I'm looking for suggestions on how I might solve the following problem using ValueInjecter.

**NOTE:** Before anyone jumps in and *a)* tells me I'm doing it wrong or *b)* tells me I shouldn't be using ValueInjecter - please don't. beacuse *a)* I have no control over the source data and *b)* ValueInjecter is used everywhere else in the project, for every other data morphing task so using a different toolkit is really not an option)

## The Problem

From a set of 3rd party service classes, I receive inbound data that is formatted as a keyed string array.  That is, my inbound object looks something like this:

```
var inboundData  = string[];
var field1 = inboundData["field1"];
var field2 = inboundData["field2"];
var field3 = inboundData["field3"];
var field4 = inboundData["field4"];
```

(*note: this is not real data, just a mockup of what I'm dealing with*)

The main premise here is that to get at a field in the inbound data i either have to specify a field name, or an array index, I can't change this as the library that provides the data is supplied by a 3rd party who won't change things, and which our licence doesn't permit me to change.

Each inbound data packet contains only the fields for one record, so if I have multiple rows to deal with what I actually have is an array of arrays, but I'm not worried about transforming that just yet, I want to tackle transforming only a single record first.

What I need to do therefore, is to take:

```
var inboundData  = string[];
var field1 = inboundData["field1"];
var field2 = inboundData["field2"];
var field3 = inboundData["field3"];
var field4 = inboundData["field4"];
```

and transform it to:

```
public class inboundData
{
  public string field1 { get; set; }
  public string field2 { get; set; }
  public string field3 { get; set; }
  public string field4 { get; set; }
}
```

if possible, I'd like to be able to do this using ValueInjecter so that array key **["blah"]** is mapped to object property **blah** automatically should any field names be changed.

## The Current Solution

At the moment, the data is transformed, but using the old fashioned method of:

```
var inboundData = inboundService.GetNextRecord();
InboudDataObject = new InboundDataObject
{
  field1 = inboundData["field1"],
  field2 = inboundData["field2"],
  field3 = inboundData["field3"],
  field4 = inboundData["field4"]
}
```

While this works ok, there are going to be problems in future, and as anyone who's done this before will know it's a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.

I'd therefore like to be able to just do something like:

```
var inboundData = inboundService.GetNextRecord();
InboudDataObject = new InboundDataObject().InjectFrom(inboundData);
```

So that if the 3rd party add a field to their record all I have to do is add a field of that name to my object.

Right now, I have a couple of experiments I'm going to try, but after a day or twos worth of research I've not turned up anything concrete, I've found a couple of posts of performing a similar task using Auto-Mapper, but I'm not using Auto-Mapper so at best all I get from them is a few ideas (That's where my Experiments came from).

So there we have it, anyone out there have any ideas/thoughts on how to tackle this one?

Cheers
Shawty

## Update 7/5/2015

So about 24 hours later, "Omu" the creator of ValueInjecter solves my problem in one go (Many Thanks), I though however I would share the approach I'd been toying with since I posted this question, even though it's a little incomplete.

After reading various things last night, I decided to experiment with trying to fill a dynamic object from the string array, with the intention that I could then just do a property to property injection from the anonymous/dynamic object into my concrete class.

This approach would actually have worked except for one problem "*not being able to run extension methods on dynamic objects.*" however, some one out there may very well figure out the final piece of the puzzle, so here's my experimental code, so folks can see where my thoughts where:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using Omu.ValueInjecter;

namespace dynamic_mapping_test
{
  public class DestinationObject
  {
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public int field2 { get; set; }
    public string[] field3 { get; set; }
    public bool field4 { get; set; }
    public double field5 { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    private static Dictionary<string, object> sourceData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    static void Main()
    {
      sourceData["field1"] = "A person";
      sourceData["field2"] = 20;
      sourceData["field3"] = new string[] {"A thing", "A thing"};
      sourceData["field4"] = false;
      sourceData["field5"] = 999.999;

      var eo = new ExpandoObject();
      var eoCollection = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) eo;

      foreach (var inputObject in sourceData)
      {
        eoCollection.Add(inputObject);
      }

      dynamic eoDynamic = eo;

      DestinationObject myObject = new DestinationObject().InjectFrom((object)eoDynamic) as DestinationObject;
    }

  }
}
```

I'm marking Omu's post as the answer though, because that solves the problem now, the rest is just **food for thought**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do the same thing as here: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DALSample/ReaderInjection.cs

except in your case it will be `KnownSourceValueInjection<string[]>`

Comment: What can I say except, you rock :-)  That's a perfect solution.  I was considering writing my own injection so solve the problem, and given that the data I'm receiving, I think is coming from a DataSet originally anyway, then that was just the perfect solution.  I am however going to update my question with a bit of research.